# Is there a way to set the width of each field at one shot instead of setting every time using streamio?

Tags: c++, iostream

I need to get the date and month in two digit format. But instead of using setw all the time, is there a single setting to say that set every field to minimum 'x' length.

```
void getDate(std::string& m_resultDate)
{

    time_t curTime;
    struct tm *curTimeInfo;
    std::stringstream sCurDateTime(std::stringstream::out | std::stringstream::in);

    time(&curTime);
    curTimeInfo = localtime(&curTime);

    sCurDateTime.width(4);
    sCurDateTime.fill('0');

    sCurDateTime << ( curTimeInfo->tm_year + 1900 );
    sCurDateTime.width(2);
    sCurDateTime.fill('0');

    sCurDateTime << ( curTimeInfo->tm_mon) ;

    sCurDateTime.width(2);
    sCurDateTime.fill('0');
    sCurDateTime << ( curTimeInfo->tm_mday) ;

    m_resultDate = sCurDateTime.str();

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there is no way to set the width for all fields at one shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iostreams are fickle, and you cannot really rely on the various formatting flags to persist. However, you can use `<iomanip>` to write things a bit more concisely:

```
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
o << setw(2) << setfill('0') << x;
```

Modifiers like `o << hex` and `o << uppercase` usually persist, while precision and field width modifiers don't. Not sure about the fill character.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the C++ streams are not really suited to formatting things. Compare with this simple code:

```
#include <cstring>

char buf[9];
std::snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%04d%02d%02d",
    curTimeInfo->tm_year + 1900, 
    curTimeInfo->tm_mon + 1, // note the +1 here
    curTimeInfo->tm_mday);
```

Maybe it's not the real complicated C++ style, but it's clear and concise.

Comment: `printf` and family are a lot more prone to bugs (type mismatches, argument counts, etc.) but I agree with you anyway.

Comment: You're right, I didn't really think about possible type mismatches. In this case there is no problem since all members of `struct tm` are defined to be of type `int`, but in others cases it's much more difficult.

Comment: Modern compilers and static analyzers are format string aware. So, I would say that for modern compilers the type safety of streams is not applicable, at least for a large amount of cases.  Many C++ frameworks provide some 'printf' type formatting.  Example Qt QString and Microsoft CString.  Some types of format strings can be a security concern but not those this question would use.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you find yourself doing something over and over again, you should wrap it in a function. It's an application of the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
void OutputFormattedInteger(std::stringstream & stream, int value, int width)
{
    stream.width(width);
    stream.fill('0');
    stream << value;
}

OutputFormattedInteger( sCurDateTime, curTimeInfo->tm_year + 1900, 4 );
OutputFormattedInteger( sCurDateTime, curTimeInfo->tm_mon, 2) ;
OutputFormattedInteger( sCurDateTime, curTimeInfo->tm_mday, 2) ;
```

Comment: Mark, I'm aware of that. I just wanted to know, if there is a easier way to set the width for all fields instead of doing setw for each field.

Comment: @user373215, sure no problem. It's just nice to know of workarounds when what you want to do is impossible, which I'm not stating is the case for this particular question. It's also useful for others who stumble across the question later.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Appreciate your inputs.